# Knowing the total price of stamps of two denomination, find the number of stamps of each kind

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

A man buys postage stamps of denominations $3$ paise and $5$ paise, for Rs $1$. He buys $22$ stamps in all. Find the number of $3$ paise stamps bought by him. (100p= 1 Rs)

I tried,
Let the number of 3 p coins be $x$

Let the number of 5 p coins be $y$

Total cost $=$ Rs $1.00 = 100$ paise

$$3x + 5 y = 100 \tag{1}$$

What should be the second equation?

Comment: The second one should be the number of stamps. Try using the number of 3 paise stamps as x and the number of 5 paise stamps as y.

Comment: really? 1p=100 Rs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$p+q=22$

and

$3p+5q=100$   (yes, because 1 Rs. = 100 paise! and not other way round)

where, $p$ is the number of 3 paise stamps and $q$ is the number of 5 paise stamps.

Thats, 2 equation and 2 unknown, how hard is that?